# How does the block form of Array#new work given "Array.new(10) { |e| e = e * 2 }"?

Tags: arrays, ruby, constructor, ruby-block

I am having trouble understanding the part inside the curly braces.

```
Array.new(10) { |e| e = e * 2 }
# => [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
```

I get that a new array with ten values is created, but what is the second half doing?

Comment: The part in braces is a lambda, for each index in the array set the value at that index to two times the index. Thus you get `[0,9]` * 2

Comment: It's something called a [`Block` in Ruby](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Array.html). It allows you to basically pass code to a method to execute. In this case, the initializer for `Array` in Ruby.

Comment: just naming things, this should be more clear: 
  nums = Array.new(10) { |index| value = index * 2 }

Comment: Have you checked out [Ruby's excellent documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Array.html#method-c-new)?

Comment: @dpa You make a good point. Part of the confusion is that it isn't obvious to newcomers that the block is taking the index, rather than than the value of an array element. You might want to post that as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

Let's go over this in details:

```
nums = Array.new(10)
```

This creates a new array with 10 elements. For each array element it passes control to the block specified by:

```
{ |e| e = e * 2 }
```

The `|e|` represents the element's index. The index is the position in the array. This starts at 0 and ends at 9 since the array has 10 elements. The second part multiplies the index by 2 and returns the value. This is because the `e * 2`, being the last statement in the block, is returned. **The value returned is then applied to that element's value.** So we end up with the following array:

```
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
```

**EDIT**

As mentioned by pjs and to avoid problems down the road, a simpler way to write the same code would be:

```
Array.new(10) { |e| e * 2 }
```

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that `e = e * 2` can be shortened to just `e * 2`.

Comment: Yes, I wondered if I should include that but I didn't want to confuse OP.

Comment: It might avoid downstream confusion.  OP may think that the block requires an explicit assignment, rather than understanding that the result yielded by the block evaluation becomes the value of the current index.  I use this all the time to create arrays of random values, for instance to test sorting algorithms or statistical techniques.  E.g. -  `Array.new(10_000) { rand }`.

Comment: Hey this is really helpful! i think i get it now. thanks:)

Answer (score 2):

### What Your Code Does

> ```
> nums = Array.new(10) { |e| e = e * 2 }
> ```

Break it down step by step in IRB or Pry to see what your code is really doing. For example:

1. `Array.new(10)` creates an array with 10 elements.
2. `Array.new(10) { |e| puts e }` prints the index of each element, which will be 0..9.
3. The construct `{ |e| e = e * 2 }`, or more idiomatically `{ |e| e * 2 }`, is a Ruby block that multiplies the index of each element passed to the block variable *e* by 2.
4. `nums = Array.new(10) { |e| e = e * 2 }` takes the result of the block and stores it in the variable *nums*.

Note that this stored array is created via the block form of [Array#new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-c-new), which says that when using the block form of the constructor:

> [A]n array of the given size is created. Each element in this array is created by passing the element’s index to the given block and storing the return value.

The example in the original post is certainly valid Ruby code, but not particularly clear. The same result can be had with more explicit code, such as the example below.

### One of Many Clearer Alternatives

There's always more than one way to do things, especially in Ruby. If you want to be more explicit about what your code is doing, use a less "magical" construct. For example, your code is roughly equivalent to:

```
num_array = 0.upto(9).map { |int| int * 2 }
#=> [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
```

Comment: Any idea why this answer got a down vote? Did someone not like the clarity of this answer, or is there a part of it that is definitely incorrect?

Comment: @TonyDiNitto No, it's correct. There are certain people (who shall remain nameless to avoid mudslinging) who routinely downvote my answers because they are "getting back at me" for past downvotes on their answers. I lose zero sleep over it.  --Feel free to try the answer yourself, and see if it helps you or not.

Comment: `Array` method taking a block is precisely designed for this kind of situation. There is nothing more direct that that. Introducing an alternative way is fine, but writing it as "one of many clearer alternatives" or "explicit", or calling the original construct "magical" is clearly wrong. That may be the reason.

Comment: @CodeGnome if one user is continuously downvoting you, does SO detect this and eventually correct your score?

Comment: @sagarpandya82 You can see this issue discussed extensively on meta. There are algorithms in place to deal with egregious serial downvotes, but they don't really catch this sort of routine but intermittent behavior. Every community has its special snowflakes; you just have to have a thick skin on SO and let the quality of your answers speak for themselves over time. --More discussion on this is probably not appropriate in comments, as it has nothing to do with the content of the OP's question or my answer.